# How to get the color scheme in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to get the color scheme of the app to give some styles to a button content. I want to use it in a foregroundColor for example.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it's pretty easy. You just need to do this:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

Button {} label: {
    Text("Hello World")
}.foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
```